# All my Aamzon SES SMTP ports are blocked

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses

Today, I found out all my SMTP ports in Amazon SES are not open.

```
Port 25 not opened on your server errornum: 110 : Connection timed out
Port 2525 not opened on your server errornum: 110 : Connection timed out
Port 587 not opened on your server errornum: 110 : Connection timed out
Port 465 not opened on your server errornum: 110 : Connection timed out
```

I failed to understand what's going on. Can anybody shed some light as to what needs to be done> This is a live server and all the new registrations are not getting emails

Comment: This is expected behavior [for port 25 only](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html).  It sounds more like you don't have outbound Internet access at all.  Does this machine have only a private IP?  If so, do you have a NAT gateway or NAT instance?  Can you access anything external, outbound?

Comment: The SES is in Ireland while the 2 instances running is based in Singapore. The Outbound access given for the 2 instances security group is set to "All Traffic". Both the 2 instances are working fine. It was working fine and found out only today that there's been an error and our email server was down!!

Comment: How does `traceroute` look?  If the instances are behind ELB, it's possible for them to serve incoming requests successfully, with internally-originated outbound requests impossible with misconfigured routing or NAT.  That was the origin of my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

By default most of the providers block the outgoing SMTP connection. This is done in order to protect the network and infrastructure from Spamming. You need to contact SES support to unblock the port or use some port free mode of email sending. Means instead of connecting over SMTP, connect over HTTP API for sending emails.